# summary.lm output customization

Tags: r, lm

I would like my lm summary output to be a little more compact than usual.  I want to remove some newlines, the "Residuals" section, the line with the word "Coefficients".  on the positive side, `summary.lm` is written as a native R function, so presumably I can just copy it to a file, change it, and then source it through my `.Rprofile`.  on the negative side, when I try the first step (copy into emacs and source it), it complains that `qr.lm` is not found.  is there magic, or am I missing something?

how do I redefine it?

```
summary.lm <- function(object, correlation = FALSE, symbolic.cor = FALSE,
      print.residstable = TRUE, succinct = FALSE, ...)
```

whatever I will get is not ideal.  if someone upstream makes a change in summary.lm, I will have to redo my code.   still, in the absence of parameters to control the printing verbosity, I don't know how else to do this.

Comment: for the bigger picture, I think you are actually needing to edit `stats:::print.summary.lm`, but it might be easier to remove the lm class of your summary object and select what you want from the list and print that however

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, redefining `summary.lm` is the way to go for what you want to do.

What you are missing is the concept of namespace in R. `summary.lm`is a function from the stats package and so has access to internal functions of this package. Only some functions from a package are exported and available once the package is loaded.

`qr.lm` is precisely such an internal function. It is accessible with the triple `:::` operator (see `?/`:::``):

```
> qr.lm
Error: object 'qr.lm' not found

> stats::qr.lm
Error: 'qr.lm' is not an exported object from 'namespace:stats'

> stats:::qr.lm
function (x, ...) 
{
    if (is.null(r <- x$qr)) 
        stop("lm object does not have a proper 'qr' component.\n Rank zero or should not have used lm(.., qr=FALSE).")
    r
}
<bytecode: 0x0000000017983b68>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

As you can see, it simply extracts the `qr` component of the lm object. You can just paste the code instead of calling the function.

Comment: interesting.  I first did `?qr.lm` and then `??qr.lm` (accdg to the recommendation), but this didn't do it.  (I also tried stats$qr.lm, instead of stats:::qr.lm.)  `getAnywhere` is great to know.

Comment: actually, I should have added in my question that I do not understand why one of the most used functions in R does not give the user more control over its output.  In every new release, I am searching for this feature...

Answer (score 3):

it is the `print.summary.lm` function that needs to be changed, not `summary.lm`.  here is a version that adds a 'concise' option, taking care not to change anything when concise is false :

```
print.summary.lm <- 
function (x, digits = max(3L, getOption("digits") - 3L), symbolic.cor = x$symbolic.cor,
          signif.stars = getOption("show.signif.stars"), concise = FALSE, ...)
    {
        cat("\nCall:", if(!concise) "\n" else " ", paste(deparse(x$call), sep = "\n", collapse = "\n"),
            if (!concise) "\n\n", sep = "")
        resid <- x$residuals
        df <- x$df
        rdf <- df[2L]
        if (!concise) {
            cat(if (!is.null(x$weights) && diff(range(x$weights)))
                    "Weighted ", "Residuals:\n", sep = "")
        }
        if (rdf > 5L) {
            nam <- c("Min", "1Q", "Median", "3Q", "Max")
            rq <- if (length(dim(resid)) == 2L)
                      structure(apply(t(resid), 1L, quantile), dimnames = list(nam,
                                                                   dimnames(resid)[[2L]]))
                  else {
                      zz <- zapsmall(quantile(resid), digits + 1L)
                      structure(zz, names = nam)
                  }
            if (!concise) print(rq, digits = digits, ...)
        }
        else if (rdf > 0L) {
            print(resid, digits = digits, ...)
        }
        else {
            cat("ALL", df[1L], "residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom!")
            cat("\n")
        }
        if (length(x$aliased) == 0L) {
            cat("\nNo Coefficients\n")
        }
        else {
            if (nsingular <- df[3L] - df[1L])
                cat("\nCoefficients: (", nsingular, " not defined because of singularities)\n",
                    sep = "")
            else { cat("\n"); if (!concise) cat("Coefficients:\n")  }
            coefs <- x$coefficients
            if (!is.null(aliased <- x$aliased) && any(aliased)) {
                cn <- names(aliased)
                coefs <- matrix(NA, length(aliased), 4, dimnames = list(cn,
                                                            colnames(coefs)))
                coefs[!aliased, ] <- x$coefficients
            }
            printCoefmat(coefs, digits = digits, signif.stars = signif.stars, signif.legend = (!concise),
                         na.print = "NA", eps.Pvalue = if (!concise) .Machine$double.eps else 1e-4, ...)
        }
        cat("\nResidual standard error:", format(signif(x$sigma,
                                                        digits)), "on", rdf, "degrees of freedom")
        cat("\n")
        if (nzchar(mess <- naprint(x$na.action)))
            cat("  (", mess, ")\n", sep = "")
        if (!is.null(x$fstatistic)) {
            cat("Multiple R-squared: ", formatC(x$r.squared, digits = digits))
            cat(",\tAdjusted R-squared: ", formatC(x$adj.r.squared,
                                                   digits = digits), "\nF-statistic:", formatC(x$fstatistic[1L],
                                                       digits = digits), "on", x$fstatistic[2L], "and",
                x$fstatistic[3L], "DF,  p-value:", format.pval(pf(x$fstatistic[1L],
                                                                  x$fstatistic[2L], x$fstatistic[3L], lower.tail = FALSE),
                                                               digits = digits, if (!concise) .Machine$double.eps else 1e-4))
            cat("\n")
        }
        correl <- x$correlation
        if (!is.null(correl)) {
            p <- NCOL(correl)
            if (p > 1L) {
                cat("\nCorrelation of Coefficients:\n")
                if (is.logical(symbolic.cor) && symbolic.cor) {
                    print(symnum(correl, abbr.colnames = NULL))
                }
                else {
                    correl <- format(round(correl, 2), nsmall = 2,
                                     digits = digits)
                    correl[!lower.tri(correl)] <- ""
                    print(correl[-1, -p, drop = FALSE], quote = FALSE)
                }
            }
        }
        cat("\n")
        invisible(x)
    }
```

and now

```
x <- rnorm(100); y <- rnorm(100)+x
print(summary(lm(y ~ x)))
print(summary(lm(y ~ x)), concise=TRUE)
```

with the first print delivering the standard R printing results and the latter delivering

```
Call: lm(formula = y ~ x)
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   -0.010      0.102   -0.10     0.92
x              1.009      0.112    9.02  <0.0001 ***

Residual standard error: 1.02 on 98 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.454, Adjusted R-squared:  0.448
F-statistic: 81.4 on 1 and 98 DF,  p-value: <0.0001
```

PS: this takes statistics for real data more appropriately serious: the p-value for individual coefficients is now limited to 0.0001 and not to the machine precision.

PPS: and if the R team is listening, IMHO this should be a standard R feature.

Comment: I am unclear how to use the accepted answer to do anything. Using the function from this answer I can create an abbreviated summary. I agree it is remarkable how there is no straightforward way to customize summary.lm

Answer (score 1):

This is more of an aside than an a to your q

One infrequently-used (I think) way of editing functions in packages is `edit` which is not only a good way to get the source code nicely-formatted but it also uses the namespace so that you *do not* have to go searching for `qr.lm` and redefine it in the global or whatever you need to do for the function to find it

I fit this lm and do the summary, it is very verbose

```
(tmp <- summary(fit <- lm(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars)))

# Call:
#   lm(formula = mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars)
# 
# Residuals:
#   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
# -4.8922 -2.2022 -0.9631  1.6272  7.2305 
# 
# Coefficients:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept) 29.599855   1.229720  24.070  < 2e-16 ***
#   disp        -0.041215   0.004712  -8.747 9.38e-10 ***
#   ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 3.251 on 30 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.7183,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.709 
# F-statistic: 76.51 on 1 and 30 DF,  p-value: 9.38e-10
```

`edit` it and basically replace all the code with `function (x) qr.lm(x)` and note that `qr.lm` is not exported meaning that you need to explicitly tell r where to look or it won't work as seen below in `my_summ2`

Here is the new definition, notice I don't have to use `stats:::qr.lm` and the environment where this new function lives

```
(my_summ <- edit(stats:::print.summary.lm))
# function (x) qr.lm(x)
# <environment: namespace:stats>
```

This is how you might try to do the same thing, but the environment is the global one now

```
(my_summ2 <- function (x) qr.lm(x))
# function (x) qr.lm(x)
```

So I can try to use both but only the first works

```
my_summ(fit)
# $qr
# (Intercept)          disp
# Mazda RX4            -5.6568542 -1.305160e+03
# Mazda RX4 Wag         0.1767767  6.900614e+02
# Datsun 710            0.1767767  1.624463e-01
# Hornet 4 Drive        0.1767767 -5.492561e-02
# Hornet Sportabout     0.1767767 -2.027385e-01
# Valiant               0.1767767 -7.103778e-03
# ...

my_summ2(fit)
# Error in my_summ2(fit) : could not find function "qr.lm"
```

But both are in the global

```
ls()
# [1] "fit"      "my_summ"  "my_summ2" "tmp"
```

Comment: This is brilliant, I came here with an answer, I go back with a super useful function I had never heard of!